# How to push the polar area slices from the center in chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, chart.js

I am using the chart.js in my Angular application in order to draw polar area chart. The problem is that i need to put the image right in the center of the chart. I made it using the css, but then other problem appeared, when the value of the slice is too low it becomes hidden by the image: [Chart with the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKIFV.png). This is how it looks like without the image: [Chart without the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZF7N.png).
So is there anyway to 'push' the slices from the center on the specific number of pixels? Thank you for your answers.

Here is my HTML:

```
    <div id="perspectives-pie-diagram">
      <canvas id="myChart" style="height:100%;" ></canvas>
      <div id="pie-image-container">
        <img id="pie-image" src="../../assets/KP-logotype/KP-logotype-006F91-chip.png" />
      </div>
    </div
```

Angular code:

```
ngOnInit() {

    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
    var myChart = new Chart('myChart', {
      type: 'polarArea',
      options: {
        scale: {
          gridLines: {
            display: false
          },
          ticks: {
            display: false
          }
        }
      },
      data: {
        datasets: [{
          data: [5, 10, 12, 25,22, 26],
          backgroundColor: [
            '#544595',
            '#009EE3',
            '#009640',
            '#FFCC00',
            '#ED7102',
            '#E30513'
          ]
        }]
      }
    });
  }
```

Finally my CSS:

```
#perspectives-pie-diagram{
    position:relative;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
}

#myChart{
    position:absolute;
}

#pie-image-container {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #006F91;
}

#pie-image{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding your code snippet, have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Thank you for you comment. Done.